# How to union or group 2 already grouped results in mongodb like union of 2 CTE queries in SQL? How to get cumulative sum from two group by queries?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, union-all

I have a collection like this

```
[
    {
        "forecast_yy_mm": "18-01",
        "actual_yy_mm": "18-01",
        "value": 1,
    },
    {
        "forecast_yy_mm": "18-01",
        "actual_yy_mm": "18-01",
        "value": 3,
    },
    {
        "forecast_yy_mm": "18-01",
        "actual_yy_mm": "18-02",
        "value": 5,
    },
    {
        "forecast_yy_mm": "18-02",
        "actual_yy_mm": "18-02",
        "value": 7,
    },
    {
        "forecast_yy_mm": "18-02",
        "actual_yy_mm": "18-02",
        "value": 9,
    },
]
```

using MongoDB mongoose I want to group by date and get a cummulative sum of values like this result.

```
[
    {
        "yy_mm": "18-01",
        "forecast_cumulative_sum": 9,
        "actual_cumulative_sum": 4
    },
    {
        "yy_mm": "18-02",
        "forecast_cumulative_sum": 16,
        "actual_cumulative_sum": 21
    }
]
```

I don't want to use any workaround in the JS part as I am trying to code this as generic.

Comment: https://mongoplayground.net/p/x6bWHd2MhNo

Comment: This works. I have included another field  "baseline_yy_mm". https://mongoplayground.net/p/h-N9xmk1hY3

Answer (score 0):

Try as below:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $facet: {
            "forecast_cumulative_sum":[
                {
                    $group : {
                        _id: "$forecast_yy_mm",
                        "forecast_cumulative_sum": { $sum: "$value"}
                    }           
                }
            ],
            "actual_cumulative_sum":[
                 {
                    $group : {
                        _id: "$actual_yy_mm",
                        "actual_cumulative_sum": { $sum: "$value"}
                    }             
                }
            ],
        }

    }
```

The result will be as below:

```
{
    "forecast_cumulative_sum" : [
        {
            "_id" : "18-02",
            "forecast_cumulative_sum" : 16
        },
        {
            "_id" : "18-01",
            "forecast_cumulative_sum" : 9
        }
    ],
    "actual_cumulative_sum" : [
        {
            "_id" : "18-02",
            "actual_cumulative_sum" : 21
        },
        {
            "_id" : "18-01",
            "actual_cumulative_sum" : 4
        }
    ]
}
```